# Fonte icons BOOTSTRAP/CSS

Tags: html, css, font

Estava olhando alguns sites e vi que estão utilizando uns icones, mas sem a necessidade de colocar uma imagem, é usado uma font, eu achei muito interessante pois você pode alterar tamanho, cor sem muitas alterações, gostaria de saber como posso implementar isso nos meus código, e se alguém sabe a fonte que esse site da imagem utiliza.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para implementar no seu site você pode usar o fontawesome que hoje creio ser o mais completo: http://fontawesome.io

- Download http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip

Depois de baixar basta adicionar em seu site assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

> alguém sabe a fonte que esse site da imagem utiliza.

Não tem como saber se você não informar qual é o site, afinal fontes podem ser criadas por pessoas independentes, desenhados no AdodeIllustrator, mas existe uma maneira de descobrir usando o Chrome ou Opera:

- clique com o direito do mouse no icone e selecione a opção inspecionar elemento/inspect element:

  > [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Selecione no inspetor o elemento que tem a classe do icone ou o pseudo elemento (`::before` ou `::after`):

  > [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que no lado direito a propriedade `font:` (ou `font-family`) terá o nome da fonte usado, então basta "googlar" o nome da fonte, se encontrar na interet é porque provavelmente existe para download, se não encontrar é porque a fonte foi criada pelo desenvolvedor do site e não poderá baixa-la (até pode copiar do site que você entrou, mas pode existir alguma implicação de licenciamento, no entanto este não é o foco da conversa).

> **Nota:** Olhando para o código fonte deles consegui notar que possivelmente eles usaram esta ferramenta ***http://fontastic.me*** para gerar a fonte customizada.

Comment: o site é http://m.floresonline.com.br/ é o mobile que tem as fontes que eu gostaria de usar, teria como saber se foram fontes criadas ou baixadas?

Comment: @GustavoSouza faz o que te ensinei, usa o inspetor de elementos e veja o nome da fonte, então busca no google e depois me avisa

Comment: ali na imagem tem o inspetor de elementos aberto, a font usada é "font-icon"

Comment: @GustavoSouza então foi eles que criaram essa fonte, não foi algo que eles baixaram pronto, então não vai encontrar pra download, você pode tentar copiar do site deles, mas não sei se existe algum licenciamento pra isto, experimenta o font-awesome ou o glyphicons que são bem completos, vai ser mais fácil.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @GustavoSouza olhando o codigo fonte deles achei qual ferramenta eles usaram pra gerar a fonte, é essa: http://fontastic.me você pode criar sua propria fonte de icones.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada no site aqui e ver como funciona, muito obrigado pela ajuda.